# How to handle a pop-up confirmation box that have different button verbiage and not OK/Cancel in Selenium WebDriver?(refer description)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

I am trying to create a Selenium WebDriver program to log into Facebook and perform some operations like write a status. But whenever I launch my Google Chrome browser and login to FB I am getting an **Allow Notification** pop-up confirmation box with the button verbiage is Allow and Block(not OK/Cancel).

I tried the Alert.dismiss method but it is not working.  I am getting a "No such alert" error and my program is not moving ahead because I am unable to click any Button on the popup to make it disappear. Also how do I handle a pop-up confirmation box that have different button verbiage and not OK/Cancel in Selenium WebDriver? Please help. (unable to add the screenshot of the image of the notification pop-up)

Comment: did you try alert.accept() ?

Comment: Obviously I did. But the popup just doesn't go away. I tried to disable my browser notification settings but it hasn't helped.It always occurs once I login into FB through my program and come to the homepage. I am unable to proceed further into the program.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt how to handle pop-ups in Silenium while working at Oodles Technologies. Let me tell you how I do it.

Before writing a code to handling Alert message we need to define some packages these are

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;        
import org.openqa.selenium.By;        
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
```

1. void dismiss() :- It allow programmer to click on the ‘Cancel’ button of the Alert box.
                       driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
2. void accept() :- It allow programmer to click on the ‘OK’ Button of the Alert box.

   ```
                   driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
   ```
3. String getText() :- It simply allow programmer to capture the alert box.

   ```
               driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
   ```
4. void sendKeys(String stringToSend) :- It allow programmer to send data into alert box.
                   driver.switchTo().alert().sendKeys(“Text”);

**How to Handle Popup in Selenium WebDriver**

Before writing a code to handle Popup window we need to write some packages in code these are

```
import java.util.Iterator;        
import java.util.Set;        
import org.openqa.selenium.By;    
Driver.getWindowHandles() :- It allow programmer to handle multiple number of popup windows  
Driver.getWindowHandle() :-  It Allow programmer to handle the main current window
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Chrome (built-in) dialog then this will work:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};");
```

I have used this in the past to prevent the "Confirm navigation dialog" (when trying to leave the page) from appearing and it works well.

Otherwise, use this:

Driver.SwitchTo.Alert.Accept()